# Understanding Hyperledger Fabric Block Extract

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, extract, block, hyperledger

I want to receive a better understanding of a block structure of a hyperledger fabric 1.4.2 block and whats happening inside of it.
Therefor I used the FabCar Example and made one update process and extracted this relevant block.

After downloading this block for analysis, I decoded it with:

```
peer channel fetch 5 mychannel5.block -c mychannel 
docker cp peer0.org1.example.com:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
./configtxlator proto_decode --input mychannel5.block --type common.Block > block5
```

The extract of the block that follows:

Here I want to know, what is the content of the longer lines with the bytes inside, like:
1. endorser (the part over signature)
2. id_bytes (the top part:)
3. value (in the transaction I updated).

I expect to a readable version of the bytes. How can I convert or decode them? For the endorser for example I expect a certificate and a publickey behind the bytes shown there.

Thank you!

```
            "payload": {
                "data": {
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "header": {
                                "creator": {
                                    "id_bytes": "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",
                                    "mspid": "Org2MSP"
                                },
                                "nonce": "n9De6IYrKMCvyKHHCT3iv9JeDQOAspmU"
                            },
                            "payload": {
                                "action": {
                                    "endorsements": [
                                        {
                                            "endorser": "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",
                                            "signature": "MEUCIQDWlfdijJGiKFCsvev5eQptsp2ClJnXVP6yYYV9kxwBrAIgRZjPQRhXe97EV3o4VZJrt7QCejFKnpEgJbB1SHUYPvg="
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "endorser": "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",
                                            "signature": "MEUCIQCWAcc9SCtgY+dBx/bE26zkvFmC7zRpr1fOv7mWj4fuwAIgOZzea7Oukxsi87D1nSe+jT2lMBg7Av/XeC1VRP91AjI="
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "proposal_response_payload": {
                                        "extension": {
                                            "chaincode_id": {
                                                "name": "fabcar",
                                                "path": "",
                                                "version": "1.0"
                                            },
                                            "events": null,
                                            "response": {
                                                "message": "",
                                                "payload": null,
                                                "status": 200
                                            },
                                            "results": {
                                                "data_model": "KV",
                                                "ns_rwset": [
                                                    {
                                                        "collection_hashed_rwset": [],
                                                        "namespace": "fabcar",
                                                        "rwset": {
                                                            "metadata_writes": [],
                                                            "range_queries_info": [],
                                                            "reads": [],
                                                            "writes": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "is_delete": false,
                                                                    "key": "CAR12",
                                                                    "value": "eyJtYWtlIjoiSG9uZGEiLCJtb2RlbCI6IkFjY29yZCIsImNvbG91ciI6ImJsYWNrIiwib3duZXIiOiJUb20ifQ=="
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually things like that in Hyperledger Fabric are Base64 encoded.

The "id_bytes" field is a base64 encoded version of the Admin certificate of the peer that proposed the block (here the peer of org2, as the mspid is org2MSP). If you paste it into a Base64 decoder (such as this one https://www.base64decode.org/) you should see a the same certificate as the one you can find under artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp/admincerts.

The "endorser" field is the signcert of the endorsing peer (ie the peer that signs the block) after Base64 encoding. Here you have two endorsers. you can find signcerts under artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0.example.com/peers/peer0.org0.example.com/msp/signcerts.

The "value" part is just the arguments used for the transaction, once again Base64 encoded (for instance, here your arguments were {"make":"Honda","model":"Accord","colour":"black","owner":"Tom"}, as you can see after decoding).